# How to mask byte in java to get the condition

Tags: java, sockets, if-statement, byte, mask

I read `byte[]` from socket as `Param_Code`. there is a condition for `Param_Code` as below:

• Option 1: Sometimes the `Param_Code` corresponds to the ID

• Option 2: Sometimes the `Param_Code` corresponds to 0x40000000 + the ID

• Option 3: Sometimes the `Param_Code` corresponds to 0x80000000 + the ID

This is my code:

```
byte[] cbuf = new byte[4];

socketReader.read(cbuf, 0, 4);

int Param_Code = byteArrayToIntBI(cbuf, 0);

public static int byteArrayToIntBI(byte[] b, int offset) {
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--) {
        int shift = (i) * 8;
        value += (b[i + offset] & 0x000000FF) << shift;
    }
    return value;
}
```

My question is, How can i know (with if statement or something else) when the `Param_Code` is one of above option?

How can i get ID?

```
if( ? ){
        it is Option 1 and ID = ?
}else if( ? ){
        it is Option 1 and ID = ?
}else if( ? ){
        it is Option 1 and ID = ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some restriction on ID. Because we cannot apply mask in that case.

Imagine, that you got 0x81234123. It can be:

- ID 0x81234123
- ID 0x41234123
- ID 0x01234123

Provide additional condition to avoid that ambiguity.
i can only assume that your ID doesn't include first hexadecimal number so, in that case use mask: `ID = NUM & 0x0FFFFFFF`

NUM is actually your byte[4]

Comment: Param_Code is what i get from socket.
Somethimes Param_Code includes just ID and sometimes includes (0x40000000 + ID) and sometimes includes (0x80000000 + ID).
Can you please provide a if statement to be more clear to me?

Comment: code = code & 0x0FFFFFFF without ifs. But its only in case when your id limited in range 0x0FFFFFFF

Comment: I need IF Statement to know when one of this condition is included in param_code. 
because every of this condition should be treated in different way.

Answer (score 1):

this is standard bittwiddling

```
int mask1 = 0x80000000;
int mask2 = 0x40000000;
int id = paramCode & ~(mask1|mask2);// ~ is NOT,  & is AND and | is OR
if((paramCode&mask1) != 0){
   //option 2
}else if((paramCode&mask2) != 0){
   //option 3
}else{
   //option 1
}
```

im assumming ID will fit in `0x3fffffff` if not you have serious problems

Comment: I get this error in if statement:
Operator '&' cannot applied to 'int','boolean'

Comment: @michdraft added parens to fix the priority problems